# Rigidbody2D.AddForce with ForceMode2D.Impulse only applies force to the Y-axis after initial trigger entry

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to add an explosive force diagonally when the player enters a trigger. The first time the player enters the trigger, it works as intended. However, any time after that, the player is only launched upwards instead of diagonally.

This is my code:

```cs
public class Knockback : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float expForce;
    
    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other){
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Explosion")
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(1,1)*expForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be able to solve this if you run it through debug. If it is working once and that can only mean that the `OnTriggerEnter2D` is called once or something is wrong with the logic. Like I said easiest done by running it through debug

Answer (score -1):

So I found the problem in that my movement script edited the players velocity on the x axis causing the addforce to not be applied to the x axis and only the y.